# How did Riemann prove that the moduli space of compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g>1$ has dimension $3g-3$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces

Consider the moduli space $M_g$ of compact Riemann surfaces (i.e., smooth complete algebraic curves over $\mathbb{C}$) of genus $g$ for some $g>1$. I'm interested in knowing how Riemann proved that $M_g$ has dimension $3g-3$.

A modern proof involves deformation theory and Riemann-Roch theorem. In particular, one needs the notion of sheaf cohomology, which was not available at Riemann's time.

**How did Riemann prove that $M_g$ has dimension $3g-3$ for $g>1$?**

I would appreciate if someone could provide some reference to the original proof by Riemann.

Comment: I guess the Riemann-Roch theorem was already known to Riemann.

Comment: I take a look at the article, it seems degree-genus formula is already known to Riemann.

Comment: @Bombyxmori That would be amazing, considering the notion of Riemann surfaces (or complex manifold) was probably not understood by the rest of the world.

Comment: @ThiKu I believe so.

Comment: @ThiKu The issue is whether the version with $H^1(X,L)$ instead of $H^0(X,K_X\otimes L^{-1})$ was known to Riemann. Riemann's proof discussed in the answers of F Zaldivar  and Alexandre Ermenko uses only the second, more elementary, notion.

Comment: There are three versions of [Riemann-Roch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Roch_theorem). In this paper, Riemann introduced his inequality, weaker than the full version. He proved that $h^0(X;\mathcal O(D))\geqslant d(D)-g+1$ with equality if $d(D)\geqslant 2g-1$. A decade later Roch refined this to an equality by identifiying the error term in terms of differentials. I believe that the $H^1$ interpretation had to wait for the cohomology of coherent sheaves, almost a century later. @WillSawin

Comment: @BenWieland Thanks,  I didn't know the exact history but that makes perfect sense, and of course only the equality if  $d \geq 2g-1$ (or even  $d$ sufficiently large) is needed for Riemann's argument.

Comment: @Will Savin: it seems that he uses equality (though it is sufficient for his argument to have it for large $d$ only). And his proof in the paper seems to prove only the inequality.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Riemann combines what is called Riemann-Roch and Riemann-Hurwitz nowadays.
He considers the dimension of the space of holomorphic maps of degree $d$ from the Riemann surface of genus $g$ to the sphere. He computes this dimension in two ways. By Riemann-Roch this dimension is
$2d-g+1$, for a fixed Riemann surface. (Indeed, Riemann-Roch says that
the dimension of the space of such functions with $d$ poles fixed
is $d-g+1$ (when $d\geq 2g-1$ which we may assume), but these poles can be moved, so one has to add $d$ parameters).

On the other hand, such a function has $2(d+g-1)$ critical points by Riemann-Hurwitz.
Generically, the critical values are distinct, and can be arbitrarily assigned, and this gives the dimension of the set of all such maps on all Riemann surfaces
of genus $g$.
So the space of all Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ must be of dimension
$$2(d+g-1)-(2d-g+1)=3g-3.$$
Riemann-Roch is proved in section 5 of Part I and and the dimension of the moduli space is counted in section 12 of Part I of the paper cited in F. Zaldivar's answer.

Remark. Indeed, Riemann did not know about sheaves, cohomology and Serre duality. Neither he knew the general definition of a Riemann surface (which is due to Weyl). But one should take into account that all these notions were developed for the purpose to explain and digest what Riemann wrote in this paper.

Remark 2. A pair $(S,f)$, where $S$ is a Riemann surface, and $f$ a meromorphic function from $S$ to the Riemann sphere is called "a Riemann surface spread over the sphere'' (Uberlagerungsflache). All such pairs can be constructed in the
following way: choose critical values of $f$ and make some cuts between them
so that the remaining region on the sphere is simply connected. Then take $d$ copies of this region (they are called sheets) stack them over the sphere, and paste them together along the cuts. You obtain a surface $S$ together with a map $f$, the "vertical" projection onto the sphere. Parameters are critical values.

Riemann did not have any exact definition of "Riemann surface", he just explained this procedure of gluing as a visualization tool. For him, $S$ is a "class of algebraic curves $F(x,y)=0$ under birational equivalence". Until the work of Weyl, these pairs
$(S,f)$ were called Riemann surfaces, and only Weyl defined exactly what $S$ is. Nowadays $S$ is called a Riemann surface, and a pair $(S,f)$ a "Riemann
surface spread over the sphere".

Comment: sixed -> fixed?

Comment: Thanks. I corrected.

Comment: This is fantastic. Can you explain a bit why the dimension comes out as the difference between $2(d+g-1)$ and $2d-g+1$? Is $2(d+g-1)$ the number of critical points of a function on a fixed generic Riemann surface as well?

Comment: @Yuhang Chen: the number of critical points of generic function on generic surface is $2(d+g-1)$. When you vary these critical values, both the Riemann surface and the function change. You can translate this to the modern language of fibrations. For given critical values, the pair (surface,function) is constructed by scissors and glue, as Riemann did.

Comment: To make sure I am on the same page, let $f:X \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ denote a degree $d$ holomorphic map from a genus $g$ Riemann surface to the Riemannn sphere. So $f$ is a branched covering. By critical points of $f$, do you mean branched points of $f$?

Comment: @Yuhang Chen: $z$ if a critical point when $f'(z)=0$ and $f(z)$ is the critical value.

Comment: I see. Can you explain a bit why the Riemann surface changes when we vary the critical values? I thought only $f$ changes while the Riemann surface $X$ is fixed?

Comment: @Yuhang Chen: Long discussions in the comments are not encouraged. Why don't you just open Riemann (available in English) and read?

Comment: Is the English translation of Riemann's paper "Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen" available online? I cannot find it via Google search.

Comment: @Yuhang Chen: I am not sure, probably no. German original and Russian translation are available. Klein's lectures on Riemann's theory and Weyl's "The Concept of a Riemann surface" are available in English online. They explain what Riemann did.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I apologize if it is poor form to resurrect such an old answer, but I am struggling to understand the distinction that prevents this reasoning from holding when $g=1$. I have skimmed Riemann’s paper and am working to interpret it in my knowledge of the modern language. It seems that there is some subtlety in the “arbitrary assignment” of branch values, and the question of whether such assignment uniquely determines a surface and a map from it. If possible could you please elaborate on this point?

Comment: The main distinction of genus 1 is that tori have one parametric automorphism groups, while RS of higher genus can only have finite automorphism group. It is not clear to me how clearly Riemann understood this distinction.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thank you. He does note that the argument fails for g = 1 and gives a separate argument: as far as I can tell, he talks about inducing a holomorphic function on the universal cover of the surface by integrating a holomorphic form along paths. This holomorphic form has $g$ degrees of freedom, which permit us to fix the integrals over $g$ out of $2g$ generators of $\pi_1$, and the induced function has another by adding a constant, which controls one of the branch values of the function. $2g$ generators + $2g-2$ branch points - $(g+1)$ parameters = $3g-3$. When $g=1$ there is…

Comment: …no branch point, so this undercounts by 1. It is difficult for me to evaluate this in modern language, but my superficial guess is that it is more or less the same concept as your argument above— just that looking dually at holomorphic forms rather than meromorphic functions clarifies the role of the branch points/values in the count.

Answer (score 15):

The original paper of Riemann is his celebrated "Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen" in Crelle's Journal of 1854. This paper can be found online at https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Riemann/AbelFn/

There is an English translation of Riemann's Collected Papers (Kendrick Press, I believe).

Modern accounts can be found in several textbooks or monographs, e.g., Harris and Morrison "Moduli of Curves" (Springer).

Comment: Is it possible to explain a bit the outline of Riemann's original proof?